# Strange error python 3 and pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Using pymysql with python 3.6.4 and mysql 8 on Windows 10. I get strange syntax errors. The commands, however used to work with Mysql 5.7 and they work on their own. Here are two examples:

```
create table Guest(
                    guestNo INT,
                     firstName varchar(15),
                     lastName varchar(15),
                     phoneNo VARchar(20));
```

Error as printed by python `print(ex.args)` where ex is the `Exception`:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create table Guest(\n\t\t    guestNo INT,\n                     firstName varchar(15' at line 2")
```

Another example:

```
insert into Booking
values (101, '2014-06-01', '2014-06-30', 500);
insert into Booking
values (101, '2014-08-01', '2014-08-31', 500);
insert into Booking
values (102, '2014-07-01', '2014-07-31', 500);
insert into Booking
values (102, '2015-07-01', '2015-07-31', 500);
insert into Booking
values (103, '2014-09-01', '2014-09-30', 500);
```

Error as printed by python `print(ex.args)` where ex is the `Exception`:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into Booking\nvalues (101, '2014-06-01', '2014-06-30', 500);\ninsert into B' at line 2")
```

It seems I can connect fine (not using the new authentication).

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of things that are different from MySQL 5.7 with pymysql:
1. `cursor.exec(q)`. q must be one command. Multiple commands separated by ; do not work.
2. After carefully looking at the python code, it was appending an extra `SET @some_var = 0;` before each query, thus converting my queries into a multiple statement query.
I hope this helps someone.